# How to Show Wordpress Updated post At First in the Blog as Regular post

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a WordPress Blog. I updated it Regularly. I Need a Updated system like below. 
I always updated older Post of my Wordpress Blog.  I need a system that when I will updated any older post then the older post need to be shown at First As Regular Post.
Pls Solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress saves a post with Post ID and number of other identities into database so, just by changing it's date we can't renew it or make it act like new post. It will remain old post.

You can make it's copy and publish that with edits instead. There are number of plugins for duplicating a post with a single click. Try those.

Comment: Thank Mr. Azmat for your Active Help